# MySQL FTS - Full-Text Search disabled special operator

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

In my `SQL` query I have special char `"-"`

Example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM articles 
WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('lorem ipsum - dolor sit amet' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

By default `Mysql` search and drop all rows with " dolor sit amet".

how to turn off the operation of char `"-"` .... maybe add something before ?

Comment: "-" has only a special meaning when you use "in boolean mode". Do you need that mode?

Comment: unfortunately Yes

Comment: Could you add some sample input and expected result; so what kind of results do you expect to be found (and excluded), and how do you utilize the boolean mode (since you currently don't seem to require it)? What do you want to achieve with the "-" (as it will e.g. not be treated as a word, in fact even hyphenated words are, by default, seperate words for MySQL), and could you e.g. just filter it out from the input?